# SSL Handshake failure - unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, ssl, https

We are unable to connect to https website through java. Getting error as "Unable to find valid path to the certificate". After enabling the java.net debug logs, I found below logs. I am unable to figure out where the issue is. OS used here is windows, however I also found on some other machines it works perfectly fine.
Any help will be appreciated

```
[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 6A 19 D6 FF 22 F3 80 A9   0E A8 E3 14 24 10 FC E6  j...".......$...
0010: 33 5A F6 55                                        3Z.U
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 88 95 D2 93 9A 8D 0F 37   29 02 0F AB 21 26 DF 09  .......7)...!&..
0010: 24 36 17 2E C1 CE 3D 09   24 DD 22 A8 64 E2 40 65  $6....=.$.".d.@e
0020: 37 C2 76 67 A8 4A 80 B8   ED 65 14 A5 1E 3F 23 83  7.vg.J...e...?#.
0030: 74 A0 5A 7D 26 D3 DB AB   93 2E 12 A0 DE B7 9E 6B  t.Z.&..........k
0040: 06 2D EB CD 8F 87 F6 DD   5F 1C 25 9A CE 45 7B B7  .-......_.%..E..
0050: 19 48 F5 70 3A 12 F9 59   2D 26 F6 C3 29 4F F9 89  .H.p:..Y-&..)O..
0060: 7B 7E 3A F9 26 5A F7 16   9F 78 04 CC 39 D2 41 DB  ..:.&Z...x..9.A.
0070: 3B 42 B7 0D 2C 86 CE 75   30 0E 4F 7F 95 34 5D F0  ;B..,..u0.O..4].
0080: 0E 75 A4 01 DB E7 11 E8   19 B6 18 D3 AF 01 0A 34  .u.............4
0090: A6 F1 64 24 55 82 23 65   FB 74 2F 28 C8 EA 11 F8  ..d$U.#e.t/(....
00A0: 81 F1 51 12 55 3C FE DA   7D 1B 0D 3A 3F 96 62 81  ..Q.U<.....:?.b.
00B0: 68 7D 5B 5B 98 71 78 F8   01 BE AB F1 E3 92 A0 40  h.[[.qx........@
00C0: 1C D4 6F 81 E8 5A 41 56   18 25 FE 36 A7 E7 51 62  ..o..ZAV.%.6..Qb
00D0: 0A 84 08 C0 27 64 2F A5   73 A0 5B 74 FE 70 63 45  ....'d/.s.[t.pcE
00E0: 23 2B 95 DA 07 EF A9 19   65 7D 0D 9A 77 43 22 06  #+......e...wC".
00F0: 31 AB 33 47 63 BC 00 FF   C0 5C 03 1D 9C 42 45 19  1.3Gc....\...BE.

]
chain [1] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=support@fortinet.com, CN=FG380D3917800028, OU=Certificate Authority, O=Fortinet, L=Sunnyvale, ST=California, C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 28221333724249516057731819561760398578507949032034777063361608650335936245825091132173774481287280336241037237714149159264869968133323515370756324777569666060937733472504967577381693074262134360955447955311078707268255431573272027086515405348333292006017601873861279276100396983742695690610449198248361991168795391926365693059761159899722879193770898399250362336274365607829045831588234406905977364279286752525587203321936207325790702456762629054309593962647422884106981897362572959942178334880113931073724281938078022950800684501641480584707329993654588732092664556366659194747070324124914022623228996675639770318141
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Tue Dec 12 08:22:19 AST 2017,
               To: Mon Dec 13 08:22:19 AST 2027]
  Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=support@fortinet.com, CN=FG380D3917800028, OU=Certificate Authority, O=Fortinet, L=Sunnyvale, ST=California, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    3c1f0e9b e2307009]

Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: C3 A9 67 94 F1 66 93 BC   AA 56 46 7F 80 6B DF 70  ..g..f...VF..k.p
0010: D0 94 6A 95 69 8A BE EE   BF AB 92 CD A1 2F C3 E2  ..j.i......../..
0020: 74 32 2A 5B 7C 1C 8C 57   9E F6 67 2B 3E 33 14 72  t2*[...W..g+>3.r
0030: CD FF F2 AD 2E 9E 30 E5   F5 87 35 1E 63 E5 46 B2  ......0...5.c.F.
0040: D4 05 C8 B0 45 38 40 0E   81 76 D5 C3 0A B5 2A 37  ....E8@..v....*7
0050: 78 09 80 16 2D D7 78 EF   C1 02 F4 C6 0A 05 37 C7  x...-.x.......7.
0060: 3F E3 79 3D E9 13 C2 A1   B2 07 F5 F2 86 F3 94 16  ?.y=............
0070: 5E 7B F3 32 8C E4 3B B5   32 72 E0 3D 28 87 8F CE  ^..2..;.2r.=(...
0080: 5A 1C F6 C5 4F 10 F4 6F   B4 B4 72 5C AA F1 3F AD  Z...O..o..r\..?.
0090: 47 30 1C 31 B9 A9 07 1F   B0 0E DE 97 0F EF FE CF  G0.1............
00A0: F2 C8 72 0A CB 49 F2 4C   F6 80 F5 E4 80 BD 0D 66  ..r..I.L.......f
00B0: 1E 09 FB 5C 7C 55 9B 55   2E 21 1B C7 35 CD 84 BF  ...\.U.U.!..5...
00C0: 0B C1 8C 02 D9 F4 6E 57   DC EE C7 8D 63 33 98 4F  ......nW....c3.O
00D0: C8 72 6D 90 81 A8 67 56   41 61 A0 2B 29 BD 3A 94  .rm...gVAa.+).:.
00E0: 04 3D BF 3F 52 EF 25 78   92 77 43 6F 28 93 74 BB  .=.?R.%x.wCo(.t.
00F0: 6D D1 5D D6 84 38 1E 57   81 E2 ED 28 85 98 E1 A5  m.]..8.W...(....

]
***
%% Invalidated:  [Session-161, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
pool-2-thread-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
pool-2-thread-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
pool-2-thread-1, called closeSocket()
pool-2-thread-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
pool-2-thread-1, called close()
pool-2-thread-1, called closeInternal(true)
2020-09-21 16:32:11.092  INFO 1352 --- [-exec-3 : KWT-CLX-3dff8-7ZXhAweL4zc-324532-prm-7ZXhCVGz3xX] VintajaGate.class                        : response session time exceptionjavax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
java.lang.Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Seems that your trust store does not contain the root CA cert. Copy trust store from the machines it works or import missing certificate.

Comment: PKIX validation implies there is a problem with the trust store. Could you please compare the trust store configuration in both the machines? Are they the same?

Comment: The server has returned a self-signed certificate, which is reported as "unknown". You'll need to configure your application to trust this certificate. The usual way is to import it into a trust store of some kind. You can often create a new trust store and enable it at the JVM level, but many libraries and frameworks have their own ways to do this, so you don't have to change system settings.

Comment: @AlexeyR. I am using default truststore in jre i.e. jre\lib\security\cacerts in both the machines, I have not installed the certificate of that site in any of them but still it works on one machine and in another it's giving the error

Comment: I can see some "fortinet" keyword in the log, as per our dev ops team it is firewall behind our network. Can firewall cause this issue ?

Comment: If the firewall does SSL/TLS interception, sometimes called other names like Deep Packet Inspection, yes. It intercepts the SSL/TLS handshake and gives you a certificate it creates (i.e. fakes) _instead of_ the one from the real website so that it will be able to decrypt, examine, and possibly modify your data. In order to connect through it using Java, you need to add the firewall's root certificate (not the certificate for any particular site) to your Java truststore(s). If it works in Java on one machine, look in that machine's Java's truststore(s).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I will try to add firewall's root certificate in the truststore and check again

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by dave_thompson_085 resolved this, firewall was intercepting the ssl handshake and I had to install fortinet's certificate on my truststore which resolved the issue.
Problem was this certificate was self signed, so had to install it on all that machine however in another machine it was already installed.